# WPF set parent (Window)

Tags: c#, wpf, window

How do you set the parent of a WPF window when you want to show it as a dialog? Both methods Show() and ShowDialog() don't seem to have that option.

This was possible in Java as you could pass the parent in the constructor. Is it possible in any way in WPF?

EDIT:
I'm using C#

Comment: You should edit your question and add the language you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ShowDialog() behind the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855954/showdialog-behind-the-parent-window)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

owner can be set but parent is a readonly property.

```
var w = new Window();
w.Owner = Window.GetWindow(this);
w.Show();
```

Answer (score 12):

on your "Showdialog" object do:

```
templateWindow.Owner= System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
templateWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: In a UserControl, the `Window.GetWindow(this)` doesn't work. This form does.